# Jquery Tooltips showing up at </apex:page>?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, html

Currently working on finalizing a system and to spruce it up we wanted to add tool tips to the name field on a data table to display some information about the product.

It works just fine, but there is an oddity, the most recent tool tip shown will appear at the bottom of the page.

From some tests it seems this is happening right at the bottom  tag.

Any idea what could cause this?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Account" extensions="AccountProductExtension" action="{!ActionAccountProductRun}">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

        j$(function() {
            j$( document ).tooltip();
        });

        window.setTimeout(recursivecall,500);

        function recursivecall()
        {
          window.setTimeout(recursivecall,500);
          autosave();
        }

        function Confirm() {
            if ( confirm("Would you like to set a reminder to check back with the TA of {!Account.Name}?")){
                sendTask();
            }
        }    
    </script>

    <apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="sendTask" action="{!sendTask}" reRender="out"/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="autosave" action="{!autosave}" reRender="out"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Associated Products and Services">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountProducts}" var="p">
            <apex:column headerValue="Product or Service" value="{!p.name}" title="This is the Help Text!"/>

            <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!p.Type__c}"/>

            <apex:column headerValue="Status">
                <apex:inputField value="{!p.Status__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Date Offered">
                <apex:inputField value="{!p.DateOffered__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Check Back On">
                <apex:inputField value="{!p.CheckBackDate__c}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" oncomplete="Confirm();" reRender="out">
                        <apex:param name="cDate" value="{!p.CheckBackDate__c}" assignTo="{!checkBackDate}"/>
                        <apex:param name="pName" value="{!JSENCODE(p.name)}" assignTo="{!productName}"/>
                    </apex:actionSupport>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Notes">
                <apex:inputField value="{!p.Notes__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your selector is the `document`

try adding an ID to the name col:

```
<apex:column id="name_col" headerValue="Product or Service" value="{!p.name}" title="This is the Help Text!"/>
```

then select the elements ending with that ID to apply the tooltip

```
j$(function() {
            j$( '[id$=name_col]' ).tooltip();
        });
```

Comment: So I did this. The issue is still there, and now it shows the message at the bottom twice.